# creating Managed Property for MMS TermSets and Terms

Tags: 2013, managed-metadata, managed-property, crawled-property

Is it possible to make Managed Property for a taxonomy term without creating a corresponding site column. I want to make my MMS terms and termsets and having corresponding refined Managed Property and corresponding Crawled Property, without creating a taxonomy field on the site. (I want to use it in REST API Search query). thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use PowerShell to create a Crawled property and a managed property.

You can use the following code to create and map the properties

```
Param(
 [string]$crawledProp,
 [string]$managedProp,
 [int] $typeManagedProp
)

# TypemanagedProp 1 = Text 2 = Integer 3 = Decimal 4 = DateTime 5 = YesNo 6 = Binary 7 = Double
$snapin = "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"

if ((Get-PSSnapin -Name $snapin -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null)
{
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "PSsnapin $snapin is registered"
    Add-PsSnapin $snapin
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "PSsnapin $snapin is loaded"
}

$searchapp = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication

$category = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataCategory –SearchApplication $searchapp –Identity SharePoint

$crawlpropTemplate = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataCrawledProperty -SearchApplication $searchapp -Category $category –Limit 1 

$cProp = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataCrawledProperty -Name $crawledProp -Category $crawlpropTemplate.CategoryName -SearchApplication $searchapp 

if ($cProp -eq $null)
{ 
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Creating CrawledProperty '$crawledProp' " -NoNewline
    $cProp =  New-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataCrawledProperty -Name $crawledProp -VariantType $crawlpropTemplate.VariantType -Category $crawlpropTemplate.CategoryName -PropSet $crawlpropTemplate.PropSet -SearchApplication $searchapp  -IsNameEnum $false 
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green " - Done."
}

$mProp = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataManagedProperty -Identity $managedProp -SearchApplication $searchapp  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($mProp -eq $null)
{
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Creating ManagedProperty '$managedProp' " -NoNewline
    $mProp = New-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataManagedProperty -Name $managedProp -Type $typeManagedProp -SearchApplication $searchapp -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue 
    $mProp.Refinable = $true
    $mProp.Update()
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green " - Done."
}


if( $mProp -eq $null -or $cProp -eq $null)
{
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Mapping not created "    
    if( $mProp -eq $null)
    {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red " - ManagedProperty is Null"
    }
    if( $cProp -eq $null)
    {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red " - CrawledProperty is Null"
    }
}
else
{
    $mapping = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataMapping -ManagedProperty $mProp -CrawledProperty $cProp -SearchApplication $searchapp

    if( $mapping -eq $null)
    {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Creating mapping between '$crawledProp' and '$managedProp' " -NoNewline
        $mapping = New-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataMapping -ManagedProperty $mProp -CrawledProperty $cProp -SearchApplication $searchapp  
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green " - Done."
    }    
}

Write-Host " "
```

Comment: thank you. I enabled a TermSet for Faceted Navigation, When I go to Terms to add a Managed Property and click Customize Refiners it generates following error:

No suggested refiners are displayed, because no refiner values are found in the data tagged with this term.

have any idea why?