# Managed Properties Backup/Restore

Tags: search, powershell, managed-property

I have a tool called the Documentation Toolkit which allows me to see the difference between farm settings.

I found some differences between my PROD and QA environments were the managed properties, some are missing on QA, some have different mappings.

Is there an easy way to fix this? like backup restore the search service application content database, or some powershell?

Thx

Comment: There is differences in approach depending on version. Are we talking SharePoint 2010 or 2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what mappings we are talking about, I wouldn't worry too much about it if everything seems to work.

Both indexed and managed properties are created "on-the-fly" depending on usage in SharePoint 2013, so new managed properties could simply be a content type or taxonomy that is created on your production environment by power users or site collection administrators.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PowerShell to create Managed properties

[This](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/66766/3039) post describes how you can create these properties with powershell using [New-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataManagedProperty](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff608089.aspx) cmdlet

Comment: that was not the question. I know I can do that, how can I fix the differences easily?

Comment: You can recreate the missing managed properties based on you're information, that you have about the missing mappings.

Comment: http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Export-ManagedCrawled-7548d31b/view/Discussions

Comment: or http://www.wictorwilen.se/archive/2012/1